# Does L'Hospital's rule say to take the derivative of the limit or the derivative of the top over the derivative of the bottom?

Tags: calculus, limits

When using L'Hospital's rule, do you take the derivative of the problem? Or do you put the derivative of the denominator over the derivative of the numerator. For example: does $\frac{\ln(9-4x)}{\tan(x-2)}$ become $\frac{\frac{-4}{9-4x}}{\sec^2(x-2)}$ or do you need to use the quotient rule?

Comment: No quotient rule

Comment: $\lim \frac{u(x)}{v(x)} = \lim \frac{u'(x)}{v'(x)}$ is what you do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others have already given the answer - $\lim \frac{u(x)}{v(x)} = \lim \frac{u'(x)}{v'(x)}$ is correct - but you should think more about *why*.

Remember what a limit is - what the value of a function **approaches**. If the function approaches an indeterminate form, such as $\frac{0}{0}$, then it is useful to consider the relative **rate of change** of numerator and denominator, since this difference is important in evaluating forms such as $\frac{0}{0}$. And instantaneous rate of change is just the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

From @GeorgeDewhirst: 
$\lim \frac{u(x)}{v(x)} = \lim \frac{u'(x)}{v'(x)}$ is what you do.